# Finding a limit given a function is continous

Tags: limits

if $ f(x) = \frac{\sin 3x+ A \sin 2x + B \sin x}{x^5} $

for $x\neq 0 $ is continuous at $x=0$ , then $A+B+f(0)$ is..?

Answer is supposedly '$2$'.. According to my friend we have to find '$A$' and '$B$' such that this limit exists but would that be correct interpretation?

Comment: Find the values of $A$ and $B$ that make your numerator $O(x^5)$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, your friend is right.

Comment: A small correction: you have to find *all* pairs of $A$ and $B$ such that the limit exists, compute the limit in each case (or do something else clever), and then show that the result of $A + B + f(0)$ is independent of which pair you pick. As it happens, in this example there's only one such pair, but you don't know that *a priori*.

Comment: I suppose that you can check from consistency of equations for coeff of x^3 and x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given $f$ (for general $A$ and $B$) is undefined at $x = 0$, which is the obstacle we must overcome.  We are told that $f$ is actually continuous at $x = 0$, so (by definition) $f(0)$ agrees with its limit as $x \rightarrow 0$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = f(0)$.  So somehow, $f$ is actually defined at $x = 0$.  The only thing(s) in sight that could be varied to make this happen are the parameters $A$ and $B$.

So your friend is right: you are to find $A$ and $B$ such that $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists (which implies it is finite).

From the given $f$, for the limit to exist, we should have the form $\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]$.  (This suggests that $x = 0$ is a zero of the numerator -- which is true.)  So we will have to use some technique to evaluate limits of this form...

Comment: thank you that helped me ;)

Comment: @DDD4C4U : Glad to help.